# How to not use a custom colour in a custom TopAppBar

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, material-design-3

During cetrain times I want to use my own color resource `ColorGreen` to change the background colour of my custom `SmallTopAppBar`, and during other times I don't want to use it so that the default black and white colours are used instead depending on the device's current theme. What is the best way to avoid a possible null pointer exception? Should an 'if null' statement be used in the custom toolbar code? Should `null` be used in the activity declaration where the underscores are?

**Color.kt**

```
val ColorGreen = Color(0,110,20,255)
```

**Custom toolbar code**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.ui.components

import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.SmallTopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign

@Composable
fun MySmallTopAppBar(
    backgroundColor: Color,
    title: String,
    titleColor: Color
) {
    SmallTopAppBar(
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
            containerColor = backgroundColor),
        title = {
            Text(
                text = title,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                maxLines = 1,
                color = titleColor
            )
        }
    )
}
```

**within MainActivity.kt**

```
...
    setContent {

        MyAppTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                Scaffold(
                    topBar = { MySmallTopAppBar(ColorGreen, getGreetingMessage(), __) }
                ) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases you need to inspect component source code to understand how it works.

In case of `Text`, default color value is `Color.Unspecified` - if this value is used, color will be taken from the style or from `LocalContentColor` (of style value is unspecified too). So if you want to follow default behaviour, you need to pass this value it too:

```
val backgroundColor: Color?
// ...
MySmallTopAppBar(backgroundColor, getGreetingMessage(), if (backgroundColor == null) Color.Unspecified else Color.SomeColor)
```

In case if `smallTopAppBarColors` default value is internal, plus since it may change in the future(as material 3 is in alpha so far), the most correct way would be something like this:

```
colors = if (backgroundColor != null)
    TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(containerColor = backgroundColor)
else
    TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(),
```